# How does Collections.reverseOrder know what type parameter to use while returning Comparator<T>

Tags: java

As per Java API spec, the signature of Collections.reverseOrder is

`public static <T> Comparator<T> reverseOrder()`

And the example given in the method description says it needs to be used as

`Arrays.sort(a, Collections.reverseOrder());`

When we call the method, nowhere do we specify what type to use (what T resolves to).

How does the compiler resolve T in this case? Can the return type (T) be resolved based on the type of the object it is being assigned to?

Btw, I'm aware of the overloaded `reverseOrder(Comparator<T> c)` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays.sort() knows what kind of Comparator it needs, since `T` is specified by the first argument (`a`):

```
public static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

EDIT:

@Louis Wasserman correctly points out that we only need a `Comparator<? super T>`, not a `Comparator<T>`. Since `Object` is a superclass of any `T`, then `Comparator<Object>` (the default if no generic parameters are given) is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for answering Brendan. From that logic, it follows that T is resolved by the type of the object it is being assigned to (? super T). Right?

Comment: Eclipse confirms that the `Comparator` is being resolved to a `Comparator<Object>` in this line, not a `Comparator<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

`T` is being resolved to `Object`.  This passes, since `Arrays.sort(T[], Comparator<? super T>)` would accept a `Comparator<Object>`, since `Object` is a supertype of `T`.

Eclipse confirms that `Collections.reverseOrder()` is resolved to a `Comparator<Object>` in the code

```
String[] array = new String[10];
Arrays.sort(array, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Answer (score 1):

`T` is resolved based on the type of `a`.

Answer (score 1):

Types in methods calls can be inferred.

```
Xyz[] a;
Arrays.sort(a, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

is equivalent to

```
Xyz[] a;
Arrays.<Xyz>sort(a, Collections.<Xyz>reverseOrder());
```

From Java SE 7 something similar works for constructors, only you need to use the "diamond 'operator'" (for not very good reasons).

```
List<Xyz> xyzs = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the signatures for `Arrays.sort()` you will see that the one you are calling has a signature of `Arrays.sort(T[], Comparator<? super T>)`, so you are in effect supplying a type parameter in the form of the array type you pass in.

EDIT: I made a small mistake here, and assumed that the call to `reverseOrder()` could [infer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) the type, but without at least one parameter, no method could actually do that (see the link).

If the call to `Collections.reverseOrder()` took a parameter, then the method *could* infer the type from the call. There is an overloaded version of the method that takes a `Comparator<T>` as an argument. We can demonstrate the inference in Eclipse with the following; hover over `Collections.reverseOrder()`:

```
public class CollectionsFun {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String[] strs = new String[] {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
      Comparator<String> comp = new Comparator<String>() {
         @Override
         public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
         }        
      };
      Arrays.sort(strs, Collections.reverseOrder(comp));
      System.out.println(strs);
   }
}
```

Because the call to `reverseOrder()` in this example takes a typed parameter, the static method can infer the type that needs to be returned. However, when you call the overloaded form of the method that takes *no* parameter, no type can be inferred, so you get a `Comparator<Object>` back instead of a `Comparator<String>`. You can see this by hovering over the `reverseOrder()` call in the code below:

```
public class CollectionsFun {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String[] strs = new String[] {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
      Arrays.sort(strs, Collections.reverseOrder());
      System.out.println(strs);
   }
}
```

As the signature to `Arrays.sort()` says it takes a `Comparator<? super T>` it matches `Comparator<Object>`. So this all compiles without giving you a "raw types" warning anywhere.

Finally, if you want to show how this would work without type inference, you would do the following:

```
public class CollectionsFun {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String[] strs = new String[] {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
      Arrays.sort(strs, Collections.<String>reverseOrder());
      System.out.println(strs);
   }
}
```

The type parameter supplied above ensures that the type of the `Comparator` that gets returned is `Comparator<String>`.

Comment: That doesn't answer how the `Comparator`'s type gets resolved.

Comment: "assumed that the call to reverseOrder() could infer the type, but without at least one parameter, no method could actually do that (see the link)" - actually, type argument _can_ be inferred based on the target type (in this case matching return type of `Comparator.reverseOrder()` and type of the 2nd parameter of `Arrays.sort` - see note right before "Target Types" section in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html). And so, as @LouisWasserman and @BrendanLong answered, from the lower bound of `Arrays.sort`'s 2nd parameter, `Comparator<Object>` is inferred.