# Generic method without parameters

Tags: java, generics

I was confused with my code that includes a generic method that takes no parameters, so what will be the return generic type of such a method, eg:

```
static <T> example<T> getObj() {
    return new example<T>() {

        public T getObject() {
            return null;
        }

    };
}
```

and this was called via:

```
example<String> exm = getObj(); // it accepts anything String like in this case or Object and everything
```

the interface `example's` defination is:

```
public interface example<T> {

    T getObject();
}
```

My question:`example<String> exm` is accepting String, Object and everything. So at what time generic return type is specified as String and how??

Comment: this question may be somewhat similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827938/how-does-collections-reverseorder-know-what-type-parameter-to-use-while-returnin  but this does not answer my particular ques:

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The compiler infers the type of `T` from the concrete type used on the *LHS* of the assignment.

From [this link](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#What%20happens%20if%20a%20type%20parameter%20does%20appear%20in%20the%20method%20parameter%20list?):

> If the type parameter does not appear in the types of the method
>   arguments, then the compiler cannot infer the type arguments by
>   examining the types of the actual method arguments.  If the type
>   parameter appears in the method's return type, then the compiler takes
>   a look at the context in which the return value is used.  If the
>   method call appears as the righthand side operand of an assignment,
>   then the compiler tries to infer the method's type arguments from the
>   static type of the lefthand side operand of the assignment.

The example code in the link is similar to the one in your question:

```
public final class Utilities { 
  ... 
  public static <T> HashSet<T> create(int size) {  
    return new HashSet<T>(size);  
  } 
} 
public final class Test 
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    HashSet<Integer> hi = Utilities.create(10); // T is inferred from LHS to be `Integer`
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thats the kind of stuff i was looking for, i was expecting this but i was not sure. thanks man

Comment: you just saved my 3 4 hours of messing. LoL

Answer (score 0):

Having such generic static declaration is possible as you can do:

```
example<String> x = getObj();
String s = x.getObject();//no casting required, good!
```

BUT `getObject` method becomes vague as how would you derive `return` type:

```
public T getObject() {
//how would this method return based on T?
//one way to always cast to T say: 
   //return (T) obj; 
   // but do you figure out obj based on T, NOT possible! due to type eraser at runtime
   // a custom logic can produce diff type obj, but that's force casting and no generic usage

                return null;
            }
```

It's better to provide `T` information as argument via `Class` argument:

```
public <T> T getObject(Class<T> clazz) {
//clazz can be used to derive return value
..
}
```