# Chaining methods on a subclass object, methods that return this from both classes

Tags: java, this, subclass

I have 2 classes:

```
public class A {
    private final List<String> list;

    public A() {        
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
    }   

    public A first(String s) {      
        list.add(s);
        return this;
    }   

    public A second() {
        System.out.println(list);
        return this;
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public B bfisrt() {
        System.out.println("asd");
        return this;
    }
}
```

and a class with main, the following code in main work

```
B b = new B();

b.first("unu")
    .second();   

b.bfirst();
```

but I would like to chain methods from both class on the same object. Is that posible? Like

```
B b = new B();

b.first("unu")
    .second()   
    .bfisrt();
```

Comment: well try it and see if its possible...

Answer (score 4):

Let's break it down.

```
public A first(String s){       
    list.add(s);
    return this;
}
```

The return type of the method is `A`, so calling `new B().first("hi")` returns an object of type `A`. So when I tried to compile, I expectedly got an error saying `incompatible types`.

You could, like markspace answers, override the method and do the same but return a `B`:

```
public B first(String s){  
    super.first( s );     
    return this;
}
```

or even

```
public B first(String s) {  
    return (B)super.first(s);     
}
```

Kesheva's method requires you to manually cast when the return type is `A`, but you know it's a `B`.

```
B b = new B();
((B)b.first("unu").second()).bfisrt();
```

But, especially with longer chains where you need to cast multiple times, this is highly code-cluttering.

Here's another solution which might suit your needs.

```
public abstract class A {
    public <Unknown extends A> Unknown first(String s) {
        System.out.println("in here");
        return (Unknown)this;
    }
}

public class B extends A { }

public static void main(String[] args) {
   //compiles without overriding the method or manually casting. 
    B b = new B().first("hi").first("hello");
}
```

On [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722902/generic-method-without-parameters)  you can read *why* this works.

**EDIT:** as newacct pointed out, it can be somewhat safe, but *only* if you don't use the builder pattern *or* if you don't look what you assign to what. Consider the two pieces of code below:

```
B b = new B().first("hi").first("hello"); 
// above compiles and works. You assign 'B b' to a `new B()`

class C extends A { }
C c = new B().first("hi"); 
// ClassCastException, but you can see that instantly. 'C c' gets assigned to 'new B()'
```

Comment: +1 for the `first()` method implementation using generics, perfect solution.

Comment: Thnks for the answer. I've changed the methods in A according to your solution. but still I can't chain the method of the class B to b.first("s").second().      after typing the last point in eclipse the default proposal of methods doesn't even show methods of class B.

Comment: Mm, you're right. It has to do with how the compiler infers type. this works (`B b = new B().classAMethod1().classAMethod2(); b.classBMethod()`), but this, unfortunately, doesn't: `B b = new B().classAMethod1().classAMethod2().classBMethod();`

Comment: The `(Unknown)this` cast is pretty much the definition of unsafe. You are casting to an unknown type!

Comment: @newacct You're somewhat right, but if you follow the builder pattern, it's highly unlikely that you'll get an ClassCastException. See edit though

Comment: i found a link witch might solve the pb https://weblogs.java.net/blog/emcmanus/archive/2010/10/25/using-builder-pattern-subclasses#smelly

Answer (score 1):

I think so.  You'll have to override the methods from A in B to get it to work.

```
public class B extends A{

    public B bfisrt(){
        System.out.println("asd");
        return this;
    }
    public B first(String s){  
        super.first( s );     
        return this;
    }   
    public B second(){
        super.second();
        return this;
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this (it's very late!) so check it carefully and futz around with it if you have to.

Comment: Thanks  .!. , it works with overriding. In the project i'm working on the superclass has a lot of methods returning this and it's useless to override then. i'll stick with the code that works

Answer (score 0):

You can try casting

`B b=new B();
((B)b.first("unu").second()).bfisrt();`

Hope this helps,
Keshava.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:

```
public abstract class X<T extends X<T>> {

  public abstract T self();

  public T xFirst(){
      System.out.println("xxx");
      return self();
  } 
}  



public class Y extends X<Y>{    

   public Y yfirst(){
        System.out.println("yyy");  
        return self();
    }

  @Override
  public Y self() {     
        return this;
    }
   }
```

and in main chaining can be used disregarding inheritance

```
 new Y().xFirst().yfirst().xFirst().yfirst();
```